# Ionic image overlay

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im used `Ionic-3` for my university project ,Im attached some code for `HTML` that code for working fine for the Bootstrap, Im try to make like this code for Ionic buts its not working correctly ,

I want the image to be overlay with white color tick mark on it(As it is selected), I have lot of multiple images for my table, actually really I don't know how to do that `ionic`, I can do it Normal `HTML`

please help me to fix this,

**Ionic code**

```
 <ion-grid>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <div class="imageandtext image_grid"><p class="item-txt" text-center>Asanka</p>
<ion-label for="selimg1">
          <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img src="assets/imgs/man.png">
          </ion-avatar> <ion-checkbox color="secondary" checked="true"  style="position: relative;float: right; top:-1.5rem;left: -1rem;"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-label>  <ion-checkbox  name="selimg" id="selimg1"></ion-checkbox>
          <div class="caption">

          </div> </div>
      </ion-col>
```

**look snippet its work for HTML**

```css
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
   
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;                            /*  changed to match image_grid padding  */
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 5px);              /*  changed to match image_grid padding  */
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius:500px;
}

.imageandtext {
  position: relative;
}
.image_grid {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.image_grid img {                       /*  added rule  */
  display: block;
}

.image_grid input {
  display: none;
}
.image_grid input:checked + .caption {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.image_grid input:checked + .caption::after {
  content: '✔';    
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  width: 30px; height: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-two imageandtext">

  <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
    <label for="selimg1">
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/0geAFQz.png' style="width:200px" />
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selimg" id="selimg1">
    <div class="caption">
   
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grid-two imageandtext">

  <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
    <label for="selimg2">
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/0geAFQz.png' style="width:200px" />
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selimg" id="selimg2">
    <div class="caption">
   
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You want this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-53563s ?

Comment: @Duannx Sir , of course, I need that one, please put your answer I can accept

Comment: It's is your code. I just add a `ngFor` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any working HTML and CSS, just use it in Ionic directly, no need to convert it to Ionic component.
In `.html` file:

```
    <div class="grid-two imageandtext">    
        <div class="imageandtext image_grid" *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index">
            <label for="selimg{{i}}">
                <img src="{{image}}" />
            </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selimg" id="selimg{{i}}" />
            <div class="caption">    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In `.scss` file:

```
img {
    border-radius: 50%;   
}
...
//Keep going. Add all your css here
```